# Is it possible to increase the amount of RAM a python process is using

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am running a classification/feature extraction task on a windows server with 64GB of RAM, and somehow, python thinks i am running out of memory:

```
misiti@fff /cygdrive/c/NaiveBayes
$ python run_classify_comments.py > tenfoldcrossvalidation.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_classify_comments.py", line 70, in <module>
    run_classify_comments()
  File "run_classify_comments.py", line 51, in run_classify_comments
    NWORDS = get_all_words("./data/HUGETEXTFILE.txt")
  File "run_classify_comments.py", line 16, in get_all_words
    def get_all_words(path): return words(file(path).read())
  File "run_classify_comments.py", line 15, in words
    def words(text): return re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\lib\re.py", line 175, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
MemoryError
```

So the re module is crashing with 64 GB of RAM...I do not think so...
Why is this happening, and how can I configure python to use all available RAM on my machine?

Comment: Is your Windows version 64 bit?  Is your Python version 64 bit?  Did you check how much memory the process is actually using?

Comment: Program Files (x86) suggests that windows is 64bit, but python isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rewrite your program to read your huge text file one line at a time. This is easily done by just changing `get_all_words(path)` to:

```
def get_all_words(path):
    return sum((words(line) for line in open(path))
```

Note the use of a generator in the parenthesis, which is lazy and will evaluate on demand by the sum function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if the problem is in using re.findall() to read the whole text as a list of words into memory. Are you reading more than 64GB of text in this way? Depending on how your NaiveBayes algorithm is implemented, you may do better to build your frequency dictionary incrementally such that only the dictionary is being held in memory (not the whole text). Some more information about your implementation might help answer your question more directly.

Comment: i actually fixed it by calling a "del" in the loop that was generating the features (during cross-validation)